# How to save data from form in a specific drive

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to save my text file in a `F` drive but this file is written to a default folder of program . How to save it by guiding a path

```
string[] contents = new string[2];
contents[0] = "Name: " + textBox1.Text;
contents[1] = "age: " + textBox2.Text;
string path = @"F:\\"; // path to file
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(textBox1.Text + ".txt", contents);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a good idea to actually **use** your *path* variable:

```
  string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"F:\", textBox1.Text + ".txt");
  System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you defining a path,but you don't use it.

```
string path = @"F:\" + textBox1.Text + ".txt";
File.WriteAllLines(path, contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use [`File.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) after you created it like;

```
File.WriteAllLines(textBox1.Text + ".txt", contents);
File.Move(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + textBox1.Text + ".txt",
          path + textBox1.Text + ".txt");
```